# What to do to activate persistent sessions?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

What should i do in `Spring Boot` to activate persistent sessions ?

I tried to play with theses properties without luck:

```
server.session.persistent=true
server.session.store-dir=/some/path/sessions
```

When i stop the daemon a see a file **`SESSIONS.cer`** on the `session` store-dir which disappears when I restart the `daemon`, but the user not logged anymore (go to login page).

My Spring boot project is an `Oauth2 authorization server` (I use `Spring Security Oauth2`) which is used with the **`Implicit grant`**. The session is used to avoid the user the retype its credential (login form) when asking for a token (`/oauth/authorize`). This is the default behaviour of `spring security oauth2`

**EDIT**:

I tried with the following property too without luck:

```
server.tomcat.basedir=/tmp
```

Comment: Did you try to configure base directory? By this: `server.tomcat.basedir=/tmp`, maybe there is problem when you restart deamon, he will create another ono.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2490

Comment: You should try http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/

Comment: Thanks all for answering
@Hrabosch i already tried this property without luck, i edited my question.

Comment: @JakubKubrynski I'll take a look but using an entire new framework to resolve this issue seems overkill

Answer (score 0):

To me, it didn't work because the objects i stored in session were not Serializable.
Just check they are.

Answer (score 0):

Object stored in session must implement `Serializable` along with a fixed `serialVersionUID`. Otherwise JVM will assign a random `serialVersionUID` which will be different for each server deployment. Since it is different for each deployment, server will not able to find a previous session and result in creating a new session.

Reference:

[Why jvm generates serialVersionUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807221/why-jvm-generates-serialversionuid)